# react native expo background notifications not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, expo-notifications

So i have a react native app building with expo and i have enabled push notifications .when i click on notification i want to redirect the user to chatScreen.however, the problem is  that when app is running and i receive a notification the user is redirected successfully but when the app is closed and i click on notification the app opens but user is not redirected to chat screen .below is the code .

```
const BACKGROUND_NOTIFICATION_TASK = "BACKGROUND-NOTIFICATION-TASK";

// Define the background task
TaskManager.defineTask(
  BACKGROUND_NOTIFICATION_TASK,
  async ({ data, error, executionInfo }) => {
    console.log("here");
    if (error) {
      console.log("Error in background task:", error);
      return;
    }

    NewNavigate.navigate("ChatScreen", {
      nexists: true,
    });
  }
);
Notifications.registerTaskAsync(BACKGROUND_NOTIFICATION_TASK);
async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync() {
  let token;
  if (Device.isDevice) {
    const { status: existingStatus } =
      await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
    let finalStatus = existingStatus;
    if (existingStatus !== "granted") {
      const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
      finalStatus = status;
    }
    if (finalStatus !== "granted") {
      Alert.alert("You Must Enable Notifications For Updates.");
      return;
    }
    Notifications.getDevicePushTokenAsync;
    token = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data;
    console.log(token);
  } else {
    Alert.alert("Must use physical device for Push Notifications");
  }

  if (Platform.OS === "android") {
    Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync("default", {
      name: "default",
      importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
      vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
      lightColor: "#FF231F7C",
    });
  }

  return token;
}

const Home = (props) => {
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
  const [showAboutScreen, setShowAboutScreen] = useState();
  const [isConnected, setisConnected] = useState();
  const uctx = useContext(Userctx);
  const [expoPushToken, setExpoPushToken] = useState("");
  const [notification, setNotification] = useState(false);
  const notificationListener = useRef();
  const responseListener = useRef();
  const { navigate } = useNavigation();
  // useEffect(() => {
  //   registerBackgroundTask();
  // }, []);
  // const registerBackgroundTask = async () => {
  //   // Check if the background task is already registered
  //   const isRegistered = await TaskManager.isTaskRegisteredAsync(
  //     BACKGROUND_NOTIFICATION_TASK
  //   );
  //   console.log("registered", isRegistered);
  //   if (!isRegistered) {
  //     await Notifications.registerTaskAsync(BACKGROUND_NOTIFICATION_TASK);
  //   }
  // };

  useEffect(() => {
    registerForPushNotificationsAsync()
      .then((token) => {
        setExpoPushToken(token);
        return AsyncStorage.setItem("DeviceToken", token);
      })
      .then((i) => console.log("Token Done", i))
      .catch((e) => console.log("token Error", e));

    notificationListener.current =
      Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener((notification) => {
        setNotification(notification);
      });

    responseListener.current =
      Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener((response) => {
        navigate("ChatScreen", {
          nexists: response.notification.request.identifier,
        });
      });

    return () => {
      Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(
        notificationListener.current
      );
      Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(responseListener.current);
    };
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    const checkInternetConnection = async () => {
      const netInfoState = await NetInfo.fetch();
      setisConnected(netInfoState.isConnected);
    };

    const unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener((state) => {
      setisConnected(state.isConnected);
    });

    checkInternetConnection();

    // Clean up the event listener when the component unmounts
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);
  // useLayoutEffect(() => {
  //   AsyncStorage.removeItem("aboutScreenShown", () => {
  //     console.log("removed");
  //     setShowAboutScreen(true);
  //   });
  //   AsyncStorage.removeItem("user", () => {
  //     console.log("removed user");
  //   });
  //   AsyncStorage.removeItem("DeviceToken", () => {
  //     console.log("removed token");
  //   });
  // }, []);
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("user")
      .then((value) => {
        if (value === null) {
        } else {
          const data = JSON.parse(value);
          uctx.setuserInfo(data);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error retrieving local storage value:", error);
      });
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    // Check local storage value to determine if the "About" screen has been shown before

    AsyncStorage.getItem("aboutScreenShown")
      .then((value) => {
        console.log("first Time View", value);
        if (value === null) {
          // If the value is null, it means the "About" screen has not been shown before
          setShowAboutScreen(true);
          // Update local storage value to indicate that the "About" screen has been shown
          AsyncStorage.setItem("aboutScreenShown", "true");
        } else {
          console.log("Available");
          setShowAboutScreen(false);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error retrieving local storage value:", error);
      });
  }, []);
  if (!isConnected)
    return (
  ...
    );
```

it doesnt matter even if i register the task inside the useEffect ,nothing happens .Any help will be appreciated .